# ESLint from project overlapping in a library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I made a "library" that I'm importing and consume in a created Vue "main project":

```
import { someObject } from "@bazinga/my-custom-lib;
```

When I run this main project Vue app with `npm run serve`, it refuses to mount, stating:

```
Syntax Error: Error: No ESLint configuration found in ..path/to/my-created-lib.
```

Why would ESLint be a requirement in my library?